# Failed to bind properties under 'spring.boot.admin.client' twhen Setting Up a SpringBoot Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I want to register a Spring Boot application as a client.

I have this in the bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url=http://bendiciones.buenas.noches:8080
```

but when I start the application I got this error:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.boot.admin.client' to de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.config.ClientProperties:

      Property: spring.boot.admin.client
    Value: url=http://bendiciones.buenas.noches:8080
    Origin: URL [file:src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml]:13:9
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [de.codecentric.boot.admin.client.config.ClientProperties]
```

Comment: Can you please share your class code of to which object do you bind the property to.

Comment: I have same issue